# Python decorator does not recognize global variable

Tags: python, global-variables, decorator

The mwe of my problem I just coded:

```
from decorator import decorator


@decorator
def deco(func, deco_name=None, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f"DECORATOR {deco_name} APPLIED")
    return func(*args, **kwargs)


deco_name = None


class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, _deco_name):
        global deco_name
        deco_name = _deco_name

    @deco(deco_name=deco_name)
    def hello(self, name):
        print(f"Hello {name} :)")
        print(deco_name)


g = Greeter("MYDECO")
g.hello("Yoshi")
```

The console output:

```
DECORATOR None APPLIED
Hello Yoshi :)
MYDECO
```

I had a similar set-up in my project and I fail to understand why the decorator function deco() does not know the value of the updated value of the global variable deco_name (it prints DECORATOR None APPLIED instead of DECORATOR MYDECO APPLIED).
The decorated function hello() does know the update value as seen by the MYDECO generated by the last print statement.
I need some way to set a global variable on runtime and pass it to the decorator and would be happy if someone can a) explain to me why my approach is wrong and b) give me a fix/alternative solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The order of print statements should be a glue. The code for the decorator is called when the class is created, which is before the instance and before `__init__()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is the decorator is created when the class is made. So the outside decorator is called before you set the variable. You can put all this inside the wrapper function so it only gets called when `hello()` is called.

I'm not certain why you are using a global variable here. You can access the instance variable in the wrapper function, which to me makes more sense. Here's an example that sets and accesses both a global variable and an instance variable. Maybe it will point things in a helpful direction:

```
def deco(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        instance = args[0]
        print(f"DECORATOR Instance {instance.deco_name} APPLIED")
        print(f"GLOBAL NAME {global_deco_name} APPLIED")
        f(*args)
    return wrapper

global_deco_name = "global_deco"

class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, _deco_name):
        global global_deco_name
        self.deco_name = _deco_name
        global_deco_name = _deco_name

    @deco
    def hello(self, name):
        print(f"Hello {name} :)")
        print(self.deco_name)
        print(global_deco_name)
        


g = Greeter("MYDECO")
g.hello("Yoshi")
```

Prints

```
DECORATOR Instance MYDECO APPLIED
GLOBAL NAME MYDECO APPLIED
Hello Yoshi :)
MYDECO
MYDECO
```

Comment: Yeah the mwe doesn't make the purpose clear. I can't share my project code directly and it would also be too much code irrelevant to the problem but I basically imported a PySpark logging framework in a separate module that offers a decorator applicable to each function. For most modules it works but for one it gets tricky because a class gets initialized that gets a key at runtime that is needed for the logging decorator :D
Well, still thanks, now I at least understand the problem and can look for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure what happens here is that the deco_name is interpreted before object initialisation. Pretty much what happens when you annotate a function in a class is that that decorator is "prepared" once the class itself is interpreted, meaning that @deco is unchangable by the time you assign g.

The best option would probably be to just package hello in a different function which fulfills the function of the decorator:

```
def hello(self, name):
  return deco(self._hello, deco_name=self.deco_name, name)
def _hello(self, name):
  # your hello
```

This also replaces global deco_name by a class property.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it's something like this but seems really counterintuitive at first. The solution is sadly not that applicable as in my project I have a lot of functions in a class that I have to annotate with a logging decorator, thus creating helper functions for each one would blow up the code too much. Well, I have to look for an alternative tomorrow then.